# Преобразование Linq.Binary в int[]

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как преобразовать `System.Data.Linq.Binary` в массив int и наоборот. Необходимо для работы с базой данных. В ячейке типа varbinary должен храниться список id выбранных товаров. Может стоит использовать другой тип данных в базе?

Спасибо.

Comment: [`Binary.ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.linq.binary.toarray.aspx). Рекомендую почаще использовать MSDN.

Comment: byte[] == int[] ?????

Comment: Задача преобразования байтов в целые 32-битные числа достаточно проста (вручную, либо же `BitConverter.ToInt32` при Little-Endian порядке байт).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы нарушаете правила проектирования БД, поэтому возникают такие вопросы. Почитайте про 1 нормальную форму и про то, как в БД представляется связь "многие ко многим".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вы на 100% правы но у меня по заданию в таблице должно быть поле  Products (List of the ordered products)

Comment: В таблице или в объектной модели?